# How to exclude folder only from specific remote?

Tags: git, github

I have two folder:

```
/folder1
/folder2
```

I have to remotes:

```
/origin1
/origin2
```

I want that origin1 will contain the both folders.
I want that origin2 will never have `folder2`.

Is it possible? If not, what is your workaround for that?

(I want that someone will pull from `origin2` only `folder1` and push only to `folder`')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible.

Git tracks the content of the whole repository, and commits are “snapshots” of working directory. So one commit will always contain the full folder and file structure including the file’s contents. It is not possible to have one commit represent two different states. That would result in two different commit objects.

If `folder1` and `folder2` are unrelated, you should consider making *separate* repositories for each. So you would push the `folder1` repository to both remotes, and only `folder2` to the second remote.

Comment: Thanks. Two repo can be in the same root folder? without using submodules?

Comment: No, you would have two separate repositories. So two separate repositories on your local machine, and two separate repositories on that one remote.